# Connect to Pervasive Database using Python pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, pervasive

I'm trying to connect to a Pervasive database using pyodbc.  Below is the code I've tried:

```
import pyodbc

server = '10.10.10.01'
database = 'RMS'
username = 'test'
password = 'test123'
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER=Pervasive ODBC Interface;SERVER={server};'
                          f'DBQ={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

When executing I receive the following error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Zen][ODBC Client
> Interface][Client LNA]Connection attempt timed out. The SQL Connection
> Manager may be inactive or using a different transport protocol from
> the client. (10065) (SQLDriverConnect); [08S01] [Zen][ODBC Client
> Interface]Invalid connection string attribute. (0)')

I've seen some examples online where they are connecting not using a username/password.  I've tried this as well, but still receive the same error.  The database is active as I am able to make an OLE DB connection successfully from another application.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the PSQL database from the machine where you are running pyodbc?  Do you have a firewall blocking port 1583 from either the client or server?  If your DB doesn't have security, you should leave it out of the connection string.

Comment: More questions.  What OS, version of Python, version of PSQL are you using?  Is the IP address specified correct for your PSQL Server?  What happens if you use the server's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying it on a Windows machine connecting to another Windows machine, there might be a problem with the connection string.  I kept getting an error 161 error ( [Zen][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Zen][SQL Engine][Data Record Manager]A key has reached a maximum limit for user count, session count, or data in use, or has changed state to expired or disabled.(Btrieve Error 161)).  Once I changed the connection string from `SERVER=` to `SERVERNAME=`, it started working for me.
So, my test file that worked was:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'PSQLSERVERNAME'
database = 'DEMODATA'
username = 'test'
password = 'test123'
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER=Pervasive ODBC Interface;SERVERNAME={server};DBQ={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM CLASS;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

You'll want to change the servername, database name, and the SQL query.

Comment: Thank you, mirtheil!  This worked after changing SERVER to SERVERNAME.